# How to fix HTTP Status Internal 500 error for eclipse and tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, java-ee-7, web-deployment-project

I am new to using Java Servelets and Java web application. I was previously getting a error 400 error until I imported my web Xml file into my project, however, the project can not recognize the JSP file I currently have. My project is able to load my Html file just fine, but when I try to load anything else it keeps telling me resource not found.

here's the code

```
package emailist; 

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import data.UserDB;
import perform.User;



@WebServlet("/EmailListServlet")
public class EmailListServlet extends HttpServlet {
        
  


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                          HttpServletResponse response) 
                          throws ServletException, IOException {

        String url = "/login.html";

        // get current action
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action == null) {
            action = "join";  // default action
        }

        // perform action and set URL to appropriate page
        if (action.equals("join")) {
            url = "/login.html";    // the "join" page
        }
        else if (action.equals("add")) {                
            // get parameters from the request
            String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
            String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");

            // store data in User object and save User object in database
            User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email);
            UserDB.insert(user);
            
            // set User object in request object and set URL
            request.setAttribute("user", user);
            url = "/thanks.jsp";   // the "thanks" page
        }
        
        // forward request and response objects to specified URL
        getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher(url)
            .forward(request, response);
    }    
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                          HttpServletResponse response) 
                          throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }    
}
```

and here's the stack trace:

```
Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [data.emaillist.EmailListServlet]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [data.emaillist.EmailListServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.emaillist.EmailListServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Comment: this part should tell you enough: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.emaillist.EmailListServlet make sure that class is on the correct path, or don't use it

Comment: I've tried changing it in the web xml file and it doesn't fix anything, as well as changing the configure build path, the error says "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." when I try to change the build path.

Comment: according to your error message, you are looking for: data.emaillist.EmailListServlet. According to your code, it should be: emaillist.EmailListServlet

Comment: I tried that, still gave me a HTTP 500 error again when I redid the XML file the first time for the path.